# Problems with FindInstance in v. 11

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra, findinstance

I have been trying to solve a system of linear equations and linear inequalities with 18 unknowns. I would think that for Mathematica giving an answer to such question will be a matter of milliseconds. Instead, the kernel runs for ages, uses up the entire CPU and RAM and then stops without providing any message. Just as if I did not let run the program at all.

Does anyone know what could be the problem? (and maybe how can I get ao some answer to my exercise?). Or is it a software bug? Thank you!!

Here is my code:

```
FindInstance[{1/5 t12 + 1/5 t22 + 3/5 t32 == 0, 
  1/5 t1 + 1/5 t2 + 3/5 t3 == 0,
  Min[1/5 t12 + 1/5 t22 + 3/5 t32, 1/5 t1 + 1/5 t2 + 3/5 t3] + 
    Min[1/5 t1 + 1/5 t4 + 3/5 t7, 1/5 t12 + 1/5 t42 + 3/5 t72] >= 
   Min[1/5 t42 + 1/5 t52 + 3/5 t62, 1/5 t4 + 1/5 t5 + 3/5 t6] + 
    Min[ 1/5 t2 + 1/5 t5 + 3/5 t8, 1/5 t22 + 1/5 t52 + 3/5 t82],
  Min[1/5 t12 + 1/5 t22 + 3/5 t32, 1/5 t1 + 1/5 t2 + 3/5 t3] + 
    Min[1/5 t1 + 1/5 t4 + 3/5 t7, 1/5 t12 + 1/5 t42 + 3/5 t72] >= 
   Min[1/5 t72 + 1/5 t82 + 3/5 t92, 1/5 t7 + 1/5 t8 + 3/5 t9] + 
    Min[ 1/5 t3 + 1/5 t6 + 3/5 t9, 1/5 t32 + 1/5 t62 + 3/5 t92],
  Min[1/5 t42 + 1/5 t52 + 3/5 t62, 1/5 t4 + 1/5 t5 + 3/5 t6] < 0,
  Min[1/5 t72 + 1/5 t82 + 3/5 t92, 1/5 t7 + 1/5 t8 + 3/5 t9] < 0,
  Min[1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t12 + 1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t22 + 1/2 (3/5 + 7/9) t32,
     1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t1 + 1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t2 + 1/2 (3/5 + 7/9) t3] < 0,
  1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t42 + 1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t52 + 1/2 (3/5 + 7/9) t62 == 0,
  1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t4 + 1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t5 + 1/2 (3/5 + 7/9) t6 == 0,
  Min[1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t7 + 1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t8 + 1/2 (3/5 + 7/9) t9, 
    1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t72 + 1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t82 + 1/2 (3/5 + 7/9) t92] <0,
  Min[1/9 t12 + 1/9 t22 + 7/9 t32, 1/9 t1 + 1/9 t2 + 7/9 t3] < 0,
  Min[1/9 t42 + 1/9 t52 + 7/9 t62, 1/9 t4 + 1/9 t5 + 7/9 t6] < 0,
  1/9 t72 + 1/9 t82 + 7/9 t92 == 0, 1/9 t7 + 1/9 t8 + 7/9 t9 == 0},
 {t12, t22, t32, t42, t52, t62, t72, t82, t92, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6,t7, t8, t9}, Reals]
```

Comment: Why do you think Mathematica should be able to do this instantly? What is your reasoning? Not all problems can be easily computed.

Comment: Mathematica does well with a portion of the equations, but as soon as I include too many of them memory spikes. For example, assuming `eqns` is your list of equations, `MemoryConstrained[FindInstance[eqns[[3 ;;]], {t1, t2, t3, t12, t22, t32, t42, t52, t62, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t72, t82, t92}, Reals], 4000000000] // AbsoluteTiming` quits after ~15 seconds on my machine. So it uses 4GB of RAM in 15 seconds, and from my tests would only keep climbing. This is with only 16 of your 18 equations.

Comment: I would do what you can to reduce the number of variables/equations.

Comment: Take a half of the system and find instance for it. Then verify all the system for these values. Then add to the half of the system the false equations/inequalities and find instance again and so on.

Comment: Thank you. @user6014 I found that 4th inequality (with Min) is the game stopper, without it the solution comes within milliseconds. I was thinking that it would be easy because just yesterday I was running a highly non-linear polynomial approximation with 24 unknowns and CPU and memory use was about 30% and at the end of 4 hours all was solved. So it kills all intuition for why a system of linear equations-inequalities takes that much of memory/time.

Comment: @user64494 Even if I find an instance for the first half that can be a specific instance that fails the other half. If the first half have a continuum of points that fail to satisfy the second half I can be trying countably infinitely many times all of them and each time not able to find an instance that fits all equations from both halves. But you idea might be saved if I first take one half, solve it fully and use the solution as the constraints for another half... Thought not sure if it will be an easier way to reason for Mathematica...

Answer (score 3):

```
eqns = {1/5 t12 + 1/5 t22 + 3/5 t32 == 0, 1/5 t1 + 1/5 t2 + 3/5 t3 == 0, 
    Min[1/5 t12 + 1/5 t22 + 3/5 t32, 1/5 t1 + 1/5 t2 + 3/5 t3] + 
      Min[1/5 t1 + 1/5 t4 + 3/5 t7, 1/5 t12 + 1/5 t42 + 3/5 t72] >= 
     Min[1/5 t42 + 1/5 t52 + 3/5 t62, 1/5 t4 + 1/5 t5 + 3/5 t6] + 
      Min[1/5 t2 + 1/5 t5 + 3/5 t8, 1/5 t22 + 1/5 t52 + 3/5 t82], 
    Min[1/5 t12 + 1/5 t22 + 3/5 t32, 1/5 t1 + 1/5 t2 + 3/5 t3] + 
      Min[1/5 t1 + 1/5 t4 + 3/5 t7, 1/5 t12 + 1/5 t42 + 3/5 t72] >= 
     Min[1/5 t72 + 1/5 t82 + 3/5 t92, 1/5 t7 + 1/5 t8 + 3/5 t9] + 
      Min[1/5 t3 + 1/5 t6 + 3/5 t9, 1/5 t32 + 1/5 t62 + 3/5 t92], 
    Min[1/5 t42 + 1/5 t52 + 3/5 t62, 1/5 t4 + 1/5 t5 + 3/5 t6] < 0, 
    Min[1/5 t72 + 1/5 t82 + 3/5 t92, 1/5 t7 + 1/5 t8 + 3/5 t9] < 0, 
    Min[1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t12 + 1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t22 + 1/2 (3/5 + 7/9) t32, 
      1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t1 + 1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t2 + 1/2 (3/5 + 7/9) t3] < 0, 
    1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t42 + 1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t52 + 1/2 (3/5 + 7/9) t62 == 0, 
    1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t4 + 1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t5 + 1/2 (3/5 + 7/9) t6 == 0, 
    Min[1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t7 + 1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t8 + 1/2 (3/5 + 7/9) t9, 
      1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t72 + 1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t82 + 1/2 (3/5 + 7/9) t92] < 0, 
    Min[1/9 t12 + 1/9 t22 + 7/9 t32, 1/9 t1 + 1/9 t2 + 7/9 t3] < 0, 
    Min[1/9 t42 + 1/9 t52 + 7/9 t62, 1/9 t4 + 1/9 t5 + 7/9 t6] < 0, 
    1/9 t72 + 1/9 t82 + 7/9 t92 == 0, 1/9 t7 + 1/9 t8 + 7/9 t9 == 0} // 
   Simplify;
```

Extract equations, i.e., remove inequalities

```
eqns2 = Cases[eqns, Equal[_, 0]]

(* {t12 + t22 + 3 t32 == 0, t1 + t2 + 3 t3 == 0, 7 t42 + 7 t52 + 31 t62 == 0, 
 7 t4 + 7 t5 + 31 t6 == 0, t72 + t82 + 7 t92 == 0, t7 + t8 + 7 t9 == 0} *)

n = Length[eqns2];

vars = Variables[Level[eqns, {-1}]];
```

Find a subset of `vars` that solves `eqns2`

```
varsn = Subsets[vars, {n}];

lvn = Length[varsn];

ptr = 0;
finished = False;
While[! (finished), ptr++; sol1 = Solve[eqns2, varsn[[ptr]]]; 
   finished = sol1 =!= {} || ptr == lvn] p;
sol1

(* {{t1 -> -t2 - 3 t3, t12 -> -t22 - 3 t32, t4 -> 1/7 (-7 t5 - 31 t6), 
  t42 -> 1/7 (-7 t52 - 31 t62), t7 -> -t8 - 7 t9, t72 -> -t82 - 7 t92}} *)

eqns2 = DeleteCases[eqns /. sol1[[1]], True];

vars2 = Variables[Level[eqns2, {-1}]];

sol2 = FindInstance[eqns2, vars2][[1]]

{t2 -> 0, t22 -> 0, t3 -> -1, t32 -> 0, t5 -> 0, t52 -> 0, t6 -> 1, t62 -> -1,
  t8 -> -(50/7), t82 -> 0, t9 -> 1, t92 -> 38/147}

sol = Join[sol2, sol1[[1]] /. sol2]

(* {t2 -> 0, t22 -> 0, t3 -> -1, t32 -> 0, t5 -> 0, t52 -> 0, t6 -> 1, t62 -> -1,
  t8 -> -(50/7), t82 -> 0, t9 -> 1, t92 -> 38/147, t1 -> 3, t12 -> 0, 
 t4 -> -(31/7), t42 -> 31/7, t7 -> 1/7, t72 -> -(38/21)} *)
```

Verifying that `sol` satisfies all equations and inequalities

```
And @@ (eqns /. sol)

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be handled by recasting the `Min` expressions as a convex combination of their constituents, with the added inequalities that the convex combination be less-equal to both constituents. The function below will assist in this transformation.

```
ineq[Min[a_, b_]] := 
 With[{nv = Unique[m]}, {nv[1]*a + nv[2]*b, {nv[1] >= 0, nv[2] >= 0, 
    nv[1] + nv[2] == 1, nv[1]*a + nv[2]*b <= a, 
    nv[1]*a + nv[2]*b <= b}}]

system = {1/5 t12 + 1/5 t22 + 3/5 t32 == 0, 
   1/5 t1 + 1/5 t2 + 3/5 t3 == 0, 
   Min[1/5 t12 + 1/5 t22 + 3/5 t32, 1/5 t1 + 1/5 t2 + 3/5 t3] + 
     Min[1/5 t1 + 1/5 t4 + 3/5 t7, 1/5 t12 + 1/5 t42 + 3/5 t72] >= 
    Min[1/5 t42 + 1/5 t52 + 3/5 t62, 1/5 t4 + 1/5 t5 + 3/5 t6] + 
     Min[1/5 t2 + 1/5 t5 + 3/5 t8, 1/5 t22 + 1/5 t52 + 3/5 t82], 
   Min[1/5 t12 + 1/5 t22 + 3/5 t32, 1/5 t1 + 1/5 t2 + 3/5 t3] + 
     Min[1/5 t1 + 1/5 t4 + 3/5 t7, 1/5 t12 + 1/5 t42 + 3/5 t72] >= 
    Min[1/5 t72 + 1/5 t82 + 3/5 t92, 1/5 t7 + 1/5 t8 + 3/5 t9] + 
     Min[1/5 t3 + 1/5 t6 + 3/5 t9, 1/5 t32 + 1/5 t62 + 3/5 t92], 
   Min[1/5 t42 + 1/5 t52 + 3/5 t62, 1/5 t4 + 1/5 t5 + 3/5 t6] < 0, 
   Min[1/5 t72 + 1/5 t82 + 3/5 t92, 1/5 t7 + 1/5 t8 + 3/5 t9] < 0, 
   Min[1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t12 + 1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t22 + 
      1/2 (3/5 + 7/9) t32, 
     1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t1 + 1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t2 + 1/2 (3/5 + 7/9) t3] < 
    0, 1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t42 + 1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t52 + 
     1/2 (3/5 + 7/9) t62 == 0, 
   1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t4 + 1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t5 + 1/2 (3/5 + 7/9) t6 == 0, 
   Min[1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t7 + 1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t8 + 1/2 (3/5 + 7/9) t9, 
     1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t72 + 1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t82 + 
      1/2 (3/5 + 7/9) t92] < 0, 
   Min[1/9 t12 + 1/9 t22 + 7/9 t32, 1/9 t1 + 1/9 t2 + 7/9 t3] < 0, 
   Min[1/9 t42 + 1/9 t52 + 7/9 t62, 1/9 t4 + 1/9 t5 + 7/9 t6] < 0, 
   1/9 t72 + 1/9 t82 + 7/9 t92 == 0, 1/9 t7 + 1/9 t8 + 7/9 t9 == 0};
```

Now rewrite the system by extracting and replacing all `Min` terms and augmenting with the new inequalities. Also extract the full set of variables,

```
mins = Cases[system, Verbatim[Min][__], Infinity];
newEqsAndIneqsMin = Map[ineq, mins];
{newEqsMin, newIneqsMin} = Transpose[newEqsAndIneqsMin ];
newsys = system /. Thread[mins -> newEqsMin];
fullsys = Flatten[{newsys, newIneqsMin}];
allVars = Variables[Apply[Subtract, fullsys, {1}]];
```

`FindInstance` will handle this just fine.

```
AbsoluteTiming[vals = FindInstance[fullsys, allVars]]

(* Out[372]= {0.493288, {{t1 -> 103/8, t12 -> 1, t2 -> -(55/8), 
   t22 -> -1, t3 -> -2, t32 -> 0, t4 -> 31/7, t42 -> -(31/7), t5 -> 0,
    t52 -> 0, t6 -> -1, t62 -> 1, t7 -> -7, t72 -> 0, t8 -> 0, 
   t82 -> 0, t9 -> 1, t92 -> 0, m$96625[1] -> 1, m$96625[2] -> 0, 
   m$96626[1] -> 1, m$96626[2] -> 0, m$96627[1] -> 0, m$96627[2] -> 1,
    m$96628[1] -> 1, m$96628[2] -> 0, m$96629[1] -> 1, 
   m$96629[2] -> 0, m$96630[1] -> 1, m$96630[2] -> 0, m$96631[1] -> 1,
    m$96631[2] -> 0, m$96632[1] -> 1, m$96632[2] -> 0, 
   m$96633[1] -> 0, m$96633[2] -> 1, m$96634[1] -> 1, m$96634[2] -> 0,
    m$96635[1] -> 1, m$96635[2] -> 0, m$96636[1] -> 1, 
   m$96636[2] -> 0, m$96637[1] -> 1, m$96637[2] -> 0, m$96638[1] -> 1,
    m$96638[2] -> 0}}} *)
```

Check:

```
In[373]:= system /. vals

(* Out[373]= {{True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, 
  True, True, True, True, True}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

You get a full solution set and a lot of instance solutions, if you substitute  for all Min[a,b], Min[c,d],... by all possible combinations of a,b,c,d,...

```
(eqs = {1/5 t12 + 1/5 t22 + 3/5 t32 == 0, 
1/5 t1 + 1/5 t2 + 3/5 t3 == 0, 
Min[1/5 t12 + 1/5 t22 + 3/5 t32, 1/5 t1 + 1/5 t2 + 3/5 t3] + 
  Min[1/5 t1 + 1/5 t4 + 3/5 t7, 1/5 t12 + 1/5 t42 + 3/5 t72] >= 
 Min[1/5 t42 + 1/5 t52 + 3/5 t62, 1/5 t4 + 1/5 t5 + 3/5 t6] + 
  Min[1/5 t2 + 1/5 t5 + 3/5 t8, 1/5 t22 + 1/5 t52 + 3/5 t82], 
Min[1/5 t12 + 1/5 t22 + 3/5 t32, 1/5 t1 + 1/5 t2 + 3/5 t3] + 
  Min[1/5 t1 + 1/5 t4 + 3/5 t7, 1/5 t12 + 1/5 t42 + 3/5 t72] >= 
 Min[1/5 t72 + 1/5 t82 + 3/5 t92, 1/5 t7 + 1/5 t8 + 3/5 t9] + 
  Min[1/5 t3 + 1/5 t6 + 3/5 t9, 1/5 t32 + 1/5 t62 + 3/5 t92], 
Min[1/5 t42 + 1/5 t52 + 3/5 t62, 1/5 t4 + 1/5 t5 + 3/5 t6] < 0, 
Min[1/5 t72 + 1/5 t82 + 3/5 t92, 1/5 t7 + 1/5 t8 + 3/5 t9] < 0, 
Min[1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t12 + 1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t22 + 
   1/2 (3/5 + 7/9) t32, 
  1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t1 + 1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t2 + 1/2 (3/5 + 7/9) t3] < 
 0, 1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t42 + 1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t52 + 
  1/2 (3/5 + 7/9) t62 == 0, 
1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t4 + 1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t5 + 1/2 (3/5 + 7/9) t6 == 0,
 Min[1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t7 + 1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t8 + 1/2 (3/5 + 7/9) t9,
   1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t72 + 1/2 (1/5 + 1/9) t82 + 
   1/2 (3/5 + 7/9) t92] < 0, 
Min[1/9 t12 + 1/9 t22 + 7/9 t32, 1/9 t1 + 1/9 t2 + 7/9 t3] < 0, 
Min[1/9 t42 + 1/9 t52 + 7/9 t62, 1/9 t4 + 1/9 t5 + 7/9 t6] < 0, 
1/9 t72 + 1/9 t82 + 7/9 t92 == 0, 
1/9 t7 + 1/9 t8 + 7/9 t9 == 0}) // TableForm
```

First solve all equations an insert solutions

```
e1 = Cases[eqs, aa_ == 0]

sol1 = First@Solve[e1]

(*   {t1 -> -t2 - 3 t3, t12 -> -t22 - 3 t32, t4 -> -t5 - (31 t6)/7, 
      t42 -> -t52 - (31 t62)/7, t7 -> -t8 - 7 t9, t72 -> -t82 - 7 t92}   *)

param = {t12, t22, t32, t42, t52, t62, t72, t82, t92, t1, t2, t3, t4, 
         t5, t6, t7, t8, t9} // Sort

paramred = {t22, t32, t52, t62, t82, t92, t2, t3, t5, t6, t8, t9}
```

The remanining inequations

```
(eqs2 = DeleteCases[eqs /. sol1 // Simplify, True]) // TableForm
```

Prepare combinations for the first two inequations and get it

```
(perm = {{a < b, c < d, e < f, a >= c + e}, {b < a, c < d, e < f, 
 b >= c + e}, {a < b, d < c, e < f, a >= d + e}, {b < a, d < c, 
 e < f, b >= d + e}, {a < b, c < d, f < e, a >= c + f}, {b < a, 
 c < d, f < e, b >= c + f}, {a < b, d < c, f < e, 
 a >= d + f}, {b < a, d < c, f < e, b >= d + f}}) // TableForm

cas12 = Cases[eqs2[[1 ;; 2]], 
      Min[a_, b_] >= Min[c_, d_] + Min[e_, f_] -> (And @@ # & /@ perm), 
        3] // Simplify

cas12 // Dimensions

(*   {2, 8}   *)

ta = Table[
     cas12[[1, i]] && cas12[[2, i]], {i, 1, Length[cas12[[1]]]}] // 
       Simplify
```

Do the same for the remaning more simple structured six inequations

```
cas38 = Cases[eqs2[[3 ;; 8]], 
        Min[a_, b_] -> {{a < 0, a < b}, {b < 0, b < a}}, 3] // Simplify

(*   {{{t6 > 0, t62 < t6}, {t62 > 0, t6 < t62}}, {{t9 > 0, 
   t92 < t9}, {t92 > 0, t9 < t92}}, {{t3 < 0, t3 < t32}, {t32 < 0, 
   t32 < t3}}, {{t9 > 0, t92 < t9}, {t92 > 0, t9 < t92}}, {{t3 < 0, 
   t3 < t32}, {t32 < 0, t32 < t3}}, {{t6 < 0, t6 < t62}, {t62 < 0, 
   t62 < t6}}}   *)

seq = Sequence @@ Map[And @@ # &, cas38, {2}]
```

The 12 possible inequations reduce to 8

```
dc = DeleteCases[Flatten[Outer[And, seq], 5] // Simplify, False]
```

Now build all combinations all inequations, the invalid ones later evaluate to False. You get 16 combinations of inequations, that are all valid to give solutions.

```
out = Outer[And, ta, dc]

dout = DeleteCases[out // Flatten // Simplify, False]
```

Now FindInstance a lot of soutions. Use randomsample of paramed to not always get the same solution  (here 80 different ones).

```
(ff = Flatten[Table[FindInstance[#, 
    RandomSample[paramred, Length[paramred]]] & /@ dout, {10}], 
      2]);

Dimensions /@ {ff, Union[ff]}

(*   {{80, 12}, {80, 12}}   *)

param /. sol1 /. ff // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Proove all of them to satisfy all eqs.

```
And @@ (And @@ eqs /. sol1 /. ff)

(*   True   *)
```

If you have a few minutes time, you get the full solution of this system set by

```
redList = 
   DeleteCases[Reduce[dout[[#]]] & /@ Range[Length[dout]] // Simplify, 
     False]

(*   A very large output was generated...   *)
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer is as follows.

> {t12 -> 0, t22 -> 26/15, t32 -> -(26/45), t42 -> 0, t52 -> 217/18, 
>    t62 -> -(49/18), t72 -> 229/135, t82 -> -(1403/270), t92 -> 1/2, 
>    t1 -> 0, t2 -> 369/20, t3 -> -(123/20), t4 -> 0, t5 -> -(93/10), 
>    t6 -> 21/10, t7 -> -(8/5), t8 -> -(73/20), t9 -> 3/4}

I solved

```
{Min[1/5 t12 + 1/5 t22 + 3/5 t32, 1/5 t1 + 1/5 t2 + 3/5 t3] + 
Min[1/5 t1 + 1/5 t4 + 3/5 t7, 1/5 t12 + 1/5 t42 + 3/5 t72] >= 
Min[1/5 t42 + 1/5 t52 + 3/5 t62, 1/5 t4 + 1/5 t5 + 3/5 t6] + 
Min[ 1/5 t2 + 1/5 t5 + 3/5 t8, 1/5 t22 + 1/5 t52 + 3/5 t82],
Min[1/5 t12 + 1/5 t22 + 3/5 t32, 1/5 t1 + 1/5 t2 + 3/5 t3] + 
Min[1/5 t1 + 1/5 t4 + 3/5 t7, 1/5 t12 + 1/5 t42 + 3/5 t72] >= 
Min[1/5 t72 + 1/5 t82 + 3/5 t92, 1/5 t7 + 1/5 t8 + 3/5 t9] + 
Min[ 1/5 t3 + 1/5 t6 + 3/5 t9, 1/5 t32 + 1/5 t62 + 3/5 t92]}
```

with Maple, obtaining, in particular,

> { t8 <= 2*t1*(1/3)+t3+t7-2*t5*(1/3)-t6, t9 <= (1/3)*t1+(1/6)*t2+(1/3)*t3+(1/6)*t4+(1/3)*t7-(1/6)*t8-(1/6)*t6, -(1/3)*t12+(1/3)*t1-(1/3)*t22+(1/3)*t2+t3 <= t32, -(1/3)*t22-(1/3)*t52+(1/3)*t2+(1/3)*t5+t8 <= t82, -(1/3)*t32-(1/3)*t62+(1/3)*t3+(1/3)*t6+t9 <= t92, -(1/3)*t42-(1/3)*t52+(1/3)*t4+(1/3)*t5+t6 <= t62, t6 < -(1/3)*t4-(1/3)*t5, (1/3)*t22+(1/3)*t52-(1/3)*t2-(1/3)*t5+t32+t62-t3-t6+t7 < t72}

The above expression was subsituted in the original system instead of the two complicated inequalities and `FindInstance` did the rest of the job.

Comment: Seems that Mathematica will not manage to `Reduce` the inequalities? It does run forever...

Comment: @gwr: I think  Min commands cause problems.

Comment: I would argue that "use maple to do half of my solution" is not an answer in a Mathematica forum.

Comment: @user6014: I could not solve it in Mathematica because the kernel connection was lost.

Comment: @user64494 Interesting, thank you! It clarifies at least what Mathematica has to work out for their future versions. I will wait a bit if there is no other suggestion as how to deal with the issue for those who have no Maple (me) and then I will accept your solution.